# button click issue and blur on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web app where I need to move content based on if the virtual keyboard is being displayed.

When the user clicks the input, I assume focus and the keyboard would be displayed. I shift some content around.

I then need to know when the virtual keyboard is hidden to move content back. I assumed the best way to do this was on blur but this is preventing the user from clicking the buttons on the screen. Click/tapping hides the keyboard, then the button has to be pressed again to finally register the click. There is a submit and cancel button so on blur, I can't assume they are clicking submit and programmatically click it.

```
//issue: button click being ignored
$(document).on('blur', '.swal2-input', function () {
    if (isMobile.any()) {
        //move content
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by listening to mousedown on the element and then triggering the click from there. You